# Interval between asynchronous data loading and reloading UITableView

Tags: objective-c, reloaddata, dispatch-async

I am asynchronously loading data to an array in a getter method of data.

First of all it produces an empty array, so naturally my table loads 0 rows.

When the data is finished loading, I call `reloadData` to update my table, however, there seems to be ~6 second gap between the data being downloaded and the `UITableView` showing the data.

Does anyone know any reasons this might happen?

I use the `dispatch_async` method with a priority of high.

I've even logged each point in the process of loading the data and inserting the data, and it shows this.

Also, if I keep scrolling the table up and down as it's data is being loaded, the table shows its data as soon as it should, rather than have this gap between insertion.

**Code:**

```
- (NSMutableDictionary *)tableDictionary {
    if (!_tableDictionary) {
        _tableDictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), ^{
            NSString *URLString = @"http://www.urlToData.com/path/to/file.php?foo=bar";

            NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:URLString]];
            NSError *error = nil;

            NSDictionary *objectIDs = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&error];

            NSMutableDictionary *objects = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

            for (NSInteger i = 0; i < objectIDs.allValues.count; i++) {
                NSArray *eventIDs = (objectIDs.allValues)[i];
                NSString *eventType = (objectIDs.allKeys)[i];

                [objects setValue:[myObject initWithIDs:objectIDs] forKey:@"key"];
            }

            self.tableDictionary = objects;
            self.titlesForSectionHeader = objects.allKeys;

            NSLog(@"Done");
            [self.tableView reloadData];
        });
    }
    return _tableDictionary;
}
```

Comment: Can you post some ode please?

Comment: Reload your tableView's data on the main thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try reloading your tableview's data on the main thread like this:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), ^{
        //background processing goes here
        //This is where you download your data
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            //update UI here
            [self.tableView reloadData];
        });
});
```

Comment: Thanks! The only reason I was using a background thread was because it stopped all interaction with the app, this solution is perfect!

Comment: You still can only update your UI on the main thread, so you have to dispatch another asynchronous queue on the main thread to perform the update.

Answer (score 0):

As a slight modification of the code by @danielbeard. I would recommend that all code affecting the current object be done on the main queue. This avoids nasty surprises down the road if KVO or a set property updates the UI.

Finally, I wouldn't use DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    // Stuff 'n stuff

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        self.tableDictionary = objects;
        self.titlesForSectionHeader = objects.allKeys;

        NSLog(@"Done");
        [self.tableView reloadData];
    });
});
```

Comment: Yeah, I have done this too :) Originally it was `DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT` but I must have forgotten to change it back when trying to figure out the issue, thanks too!